# Why to multiply the penalty by $n$ in the penalized least squares and likelihood?

Tags: regularization, linear-regression, non-convex-optimization

In the SCAD paper by Fan and Li (2001), there exist two forms of penalized least squares as follows:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left \| y-X\beta \right \|^2+\lambda \sum_{j=1}^{d}p_j (\left | \beta _j \right |),$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)+n \sum_{j=1}^{d}p_\lambda (\left | \beta _j \right |),$$
which correspond to the formula (2.2) and (3.1) in the paper respectively. Why does the second one multiply the penalty by $n$ (the number of the observation)?

Similarly, the penalized likelihood function (3.3) also presents penalty with multiplication factor $n$ as  follows:
$$-\sum_{i=1}^{n}l_i(g(x_i^T\beta),y_i)+n \sum_{j=1}^{d}p_\lambda (\left | \beta _j \right |).$$

Furthermore, the Lasso paper (Tibshirani, 1996) doesn't contain $n$ in the penalty.

Why to multiply the penalty by $n$ in the penalized least squares and likelihood? What impact does it have on the criterion?

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to "Variable Selection via Nonconcave Penalized Likelihood and its Oracle Properties", Fan and Li, Journal of the American Statistical Association, Dec 2001. http://orfe.princeton.edu/~jqfan/papers/01/penlike.pdf

Whether to include a factor of $\lambda$ or $n$ in the penalty term is merely a matter of convention. I don't know why the authors did not consistently apply a single convention throughout their paper.

Taking $p_\lambda$ as $\lambda p_j/n$, the two penalties can be made equivalent.

Comment: I wonder that it is merely a matter of convention. Recently, I am reading some papers on penalized likelihood function. Some of them demonstrate that such penalty with multiplication factor $n$ (or a function of $n$) not only have no impact on the asymptotic properties of the estimate, but also reduce the adverse effects of the penalty in the case that we have no need of the penalty, when $n$ increases. Hence, I guess that the $n$ here has some similar effect to a certain extent.

Comment: It is "merely" a matter of convention. As for any beneficial effect of using 1/n rather than $\lambda$ in such cases as there is no need for a penalty, that must be because there was no offsetting increase applied to p. Only the "net" penalty from multiplying all the terms together matters.